Distance shift camera renders different: Mismatch Between Camera View and Rendered Scene
I am seeing a mismatch between the view through the camera (numpad 0) and the final render (Render > Render Image). There seems to be a distance shift. I am not sure why (I am using my friend's file to help her troubleshoot).
I’ve checked and cleared all animation keyframes, but the issue persists.
The camera is set to perspective with a 50mm lens.



You have there three separate Subdivision Surface modifiers in a row on the object "Cube": the modifiers have two resolution Levels, one for Viewport and one for Render. By default they are set to 1 for the viewport and 2 for rendering.

If you would set the Render levels to 1 like the viewport, the render will look the same:

And vice versa, set the Viewport levels to 2 like the render, and the viewport will change to look like the render:


Wow, thanks a lot! I didn't think about checking the modifiers. I was helping a friend troubleshoot her file. I didn’t realize there were three subdivision modifiers. I’ll let her know to delete them. I really appreciate it!

@J13 You can of course leave them at three, the result of three modifiers at level 1 is slightly different than one modifier at level 3: the cube will be larger with one modifier and have a slightly different shaped mesh (but same number of vertices). But it depends on what she was trying to do, if she just added more modifiers to get the cube smoother, than using one modifier with a higher level is sufficient. And if it were too large then, she could scale it down of course.
